# How do none of the of the polynomials have a degree 2?

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove: there exists a basis  p<sub>0</sub>, p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>3</sub> of *P*<sub>3</sub>(**F**) such that none of the polynomials p<sub>0</sub>, p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>3</sub> has degree 2.

**F**= is the union of all real and complex numbers

Solution: Because 1, x, x<sup>2</sup>, x<sup>3</sup> is a basis of *P*<sub>3</sub>(**F**),

hence: 1 + x<sup>3</sup>,  x + x<sup>3</sup>,  x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>3</sup>,   x<sup>2</sup> is also a basis of *P*<sub>3</sub>(**F**). However none of the polynomials has degree 2.

**My question:** How do none of the of the polynomials have a degree 2? I think I am misunderstanding the term degree in this context.

Comment: I think the last basis is $x^3$, not $x^2$.

Comment: rechecked the solution manual, it says x^(2)...could be wrong then?

Comment: It is definitely wrong because $x^2$ is a degree 2 polynomial!

Comment: That makes more sense...so $ x^3$ is a free variable which p **2** is dependent on?

Comment: @math_illiterate: The term *free variable* doesn’t really make sense here. $B=\{1+x^3,x+x^3,x^2+x^3,x^3\}$ is a basis for $P_3(\Bbb F)$ because every polynomial in $P_3(\Bbb F)$ is a linear combination of those four cubic polynomials. The easy way to see this is to note that $1=(1+x^3)-x^3,x=(x+x^3)-x^3$, and $x^2=(x^2+x^3)-x^3$, so $1,x,x^2$, and $x^3$ are all linear combinations of them. You know that these four polynomials are a basis for $P_3(\Bbb F)$, so $B$ is as well.